# Tauri Application Not Including or Accessing Folder in Production Build

Tags: rust, tauri

I'm developing a Tauri application that requires access to a C# project folder named "Audio" in both development and production environments. The application works as expected during development, but in the production build, the "Audio" folder is not available or accessible.

Issue:
The "Audio" folder, which contains a C# executable and other necessary files, is not being included in the production build or is not accessible when running the production build of my Tauri app.

Project Structure:
Root Directory
src
src-tauri
Audio (C# Project Folder)

I've included the "Audio" folder in my tauri.conf.json under bundle.resources:

```
"bundle": {
  "resources": [
    "../Audio"
  ],
}
```

In my main.rs, I'm trying to access the "Audio" folder like this:

```
let path = if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
        "../Audio/bin/Debug/net7.0/Audio.exe"
    } else {
        "../resources/Audio/bin/Debug/net7.0/Audio.exe"
    };
```

The application works fine in the development environment.
In production, the application either fails to find the "Audio" folder or doesn't include it at all(Do not know for sure, since as soon as i try the function associated with it, the application crashes and exits).

Also note that i can't just include the Audio.exe file, since it has other dependencies(which are a part of the C# project).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is very likely that the path is simply wrong. Tauri will replace `..` path components with `_up_` and `C:` with `_root_` so the idea is to use Tauri's [PathResolver](https://docs.rs/tauri/1.5.1/tauri/struct.PathResolver.html).
For this you need a reference to an `App`, `AppHandle`, or `Window` which you can get in all of tauri's Builder hooks or in [Tauri commands](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command#accessing-an-apphandle-in-commands).
Then all you have to do is this (the paths must match what you entered in the resources config):

```rs
let path = app_handle.path_resolver().resolve_resource("../Audio/bin/Debug/net7.0/Audio.exe");
```

Comment: That worked, **thanks a lot**.